# How to get location of clicked link on webpage in form of margins?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a link on webpage. When I click this link a pop is appeared using CSS.

**For example:**

```
<a href="/popup/show.php?marLft=950&marTop=400" id="MyId" class="MyClass">Show Popup</a>
```

I use `marLft` and `marTop` to set a css margins and Popup is shown on correct location under link.

**Problem:**

Now problem is that now I have some DIVs on webpage that are using jQuery **fadeIn** and **fadeOut** functionality. So location of `Show Popup` link is not same all the time and popup is not shown under the link always. How can I get location of link and pass that location in form of top and left margins to the linked script at runtime.

How it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

I think it you will help you.